How to install Ghostty on Ubuntu 24.04?
The product webpage is: https://ghostty.org, but I don't see installation instructions for Ubuntu 24.04.
How can I install it?

@ChesterGillon thanks, installed without compilation

Building from source is minimal as well, https://ghostty.org/docs/install/build.

A package from a user Fedora repository converted to deb works for me. Full terminal instructions:
cd Downloads

wget https://download.copr.fedorainfracloud.org/results/pgdev/ghostty/fedora-40-x86_64/08450395-ghostty/ghostty-1.0.0-2.fc40.x86_64.rpm

sudo apt install fakeroot alien # converting rpm to deb
sudo apt install libgtk-4-1 libadwaita-1-0 libonig5 libx11-dev # app dependencies

fakeroot alien ghostty-*.rpm

sudo apt install ./ghostty*.deb


Building from source
Ghostty's website provides a page for downloads. Unfortunately, it does not list an option for Ubuntu or Debian, nor does it list a Snap package or a Flatpak option.
OMGUbuntu posted instructions on how to build Ghostty from source on Ubuntu. Here is my summary:

Install Zig compiler, version 0.13 (it can't be a newer version!). Download the tarball from here, and extract it to /opt/ using commands like these:
cd /opt
sudo tar xvf ~/Downloads/zig-linux-x86_64-0.13.0.tar.xz


Go to Ghostty's GitHub tags page and download the .tar.gz file of the latest release.

Extract the .tar.gz and change directory into the ghostty project:
cd ~
tar xvf ~/Downloads/ghostty-1.0.0.tar.gz
cd ghostty-1.0.0


Install build dependencies needed to build Ghostty:
sudo apt install libgtk-4-dev libadwaita-1-dev


Build and install Ghostty by running the following command (this will probably take several minutes):
sudo nice /opt/zig-linux-x86_64-0.13.0/zig build -p /usr/local -Doptimize=ReleaseFast


To launch Ghostty, run ghostty

Now that you have built Ghostty, you can uninstall the build dependencies, as you no longer need them:
sudo apt remove libgtk-4-dev libadwaita-1-dev



Uninstallation:
If you want to uninstall Ghostty in the future, run this command in extracted Ghostty directory:
sudo /opt/zig-linux-x86_64-0.13.0/zig build uninstall -p /usr/local

Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work in my case. Instead, I had to run this command:
 sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/bin/ghostty /usr/local/share/applications/com.mitchellh.ghostty.desktop /usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions/ghostty.bash /usr/local/share/bat/syntaxes/ghostty.sublime-syntax /usr/local/share/ghostty/ /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/com.mitchellh.ghostty.png /usr/local/share/kio/servicemenus/com.mitchellh.ghostty.desktop /usr/local/share/man/man1/ghostty.1 /usr/local/share/man/man5/ghostty.5 /usr/local/share/nvim/site/*/ghostty.vim /usr/local/share/terminfo/g/ghostty /usr/local/share/terminfo/ghostty.termcap /usr/local/share/terminfo/ghostty.terminfo /usr/local/share/terminfo/x/xterm-ghostty /usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles/*/ghostty.vim /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_ghostty

